# Why to use the て-form in questions?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, academic-japanese

Anybody around here knows why it is used the て-form in 覚えてないのかい instead of 覚えないのかい in the next sentence?

僕はさっきもう君にすっかり話したじゃないか。
それとも、覚えてないのかい？
I've already seen this before in other question sentences
So..., What I want to know is why it is use the て-form in question sentences? I mean.... If I use both of them (覚えてないの､　覚えないの  ) the meaning of the sentence wouldn't be the same?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30433/present-progressive-tense-of-%e8%a6%9a%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b/30440#30440